# pip install tensorflow keeps downloading more and more versions

Tags: tensorflow, installation

Simply doing "pip install tensorflow" in a conda environment won't stop downloading older and older versions of tensorflow. What is going on here? I'll be out of disk space soon.

```
Downloading tensorflow_text-2.7.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 2.5/2.5 MB 9.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorflow (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Downloading tensorflow-2.7.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (436.8 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 436.8/436.8 MB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.7.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (436.7 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 436.7/436.7 MB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.7.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (436.7 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 436.7/436.7 MB 2.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.7.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (436.4 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 436.4/436.4 MB 2.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.7.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (430.8 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 430.8/430.8 MB 2.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorflow-text (from keras-nlp==0.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Downloading tensorflow_text-2.6.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 4.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorflow (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Downloading tensorflow-2.6.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (429.2 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 429.2/429.2 MB 1.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.6.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (429.2 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 429.2/429.2 MB 2.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.6.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (428.9 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 428.9/428.9 MB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.6.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (423.3 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 423.3/423.3 MB 2.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.6.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (423.3 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 423.3/423.3 MB 1.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.6.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (423.3 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 423.3/423.3 MB 2.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorflow-text (from keras-nlp==0.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Downloading tensorflow_text-2.5.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 11.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorflow (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Downloading tensorflow-2.5.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (428.3 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 428.3/428.3 MB 2.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.5.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (422.7 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 422.7/422.7 MB 2.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tensorflow-2.5.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (422.7 MB)
     ------------------------ --------------- 262.1/422.7 MB 5.7 MB/s eta 0:00:28
```